# How to let user specify log file format

Tags: c++, string, configuration

I have a c++ datalogger program. It reads from a variety of inputs and generates an object with all the values. Any given user may only need a certain subset of those values and I'd like to have a commandline argument that allows the user to specify which values will be written to the log file and in what order.

For example:

```
./myprogram -f "a,b,c"
```

pseudo-code

```
int main () {
sensora.read();
sensorb.read();
sensorc.read();
if (arg.f == "a,b,c"){
    logfile << sensora.value() << ",";
    logfile << sensorb.value() << ",";
    logfile << sensorc.value();
}
```

What is a good way to approach this problem? Are there good examples of code that does this efficiently?

Comment: I would parse the argument to split the values into an array, then loop through the array, and for each value you can write out the corresponding element to the log

Comment: An excellent suggestion! I knew there could be a simple solution, but I just hit a wall and couldn't think of anything.